# Adding xib in CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, xib

Problem such, downloaded and installed [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser), it worked all right, but that's a problem, I do not need that to show a list of the main xib news, and that he would need to show the menu that I create. But when you try to add a menu, ie create a new a new xib, I choose in the settings (general) in paragraph mainintarface, choose your new xib (MainNav) I get an error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Dig deeper into the net, I came across [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239766/libc-abi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-collecti), I understand the problem is that I have not added my new xib in UICollectionView? I porobyval remove UIKit.framework, then got out unreal number of errors. Well, actually the question how do I add my new xib in UICollectionView?

Comment: If it means you created your own cell in nib, you should use this `- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib
forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`

Comment: This question is really hard to understand.

Comment: @Dennis Look, I create a new xib and if I choose the Xib and choose it as main intarface  it appears this error

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

You need register your xib cell to your UICollectionView on -(void)viewDidLoad of your view Controller.

```
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil] 
              forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifer"];
```

Click [here] (https://github.com/lequysang/TestCollectionViewWithXIB")